# Not able to debug notificaton content extension in ios 10 notification

Tags: notifications, apple-push-notifications, ios10

print statement does not work inside notification content extension, although I am able to modify the Label text and other fields, below is my code

```
class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension {


@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("inside viewDidLoad of notificationViewController")
}

func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    self.label?.text = notification.request.content.body
    print("inside didReceive of notificationViewController")

}
```

}

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following steps pointed [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50849) worked for me:

> After running the app that contains the extension,
>
> - Set your breakpoint in the extension
> - Select Debug / Attach to Process by PID or name
> - Enter the name of the extension target
> - Trigger the push notification
> - Breakpoints in extensions take forever to trigger. BE PATIENT, eventually your breakpoint will be hit
>
> You will have to do this every time you restart your app via Xcode.

Comment: hey my crashed upon receiving notification

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511005/cant-attach-debugger-to-unnotificationserviceextension
just like this one, any thoughts ?

Comment: Any idea how long is "forever" in terms of triggering the breakpoint, 5 minutes, 10 minutes, or 1 hour?