# Can't attach debugger to UNNotificationServiceExtension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unnotificationserviceextension

I'm not being able to use the debugger in a UNNotificationServiceExtension.

Here's what I do when attempting to attach the debugger to the UNNotificationServiceExtension:

1. Run app
2. Set the breakpoint in the "Testing" UNNotificationServiceExtension
3. Select Debug > Attach to Process by PID or Name > Select the "Testing" UNNotificationServiceExtension
4. XCode indicates that the "Testing is waiting to attach"

[image: "Testing" extension waiting to attach]

5. I then send a push notification and my iPhone displays the notification, but the debugger doesn't hit the breakpoint. Instead, XCode shows a "Thread1: signal SIGKILL".

[image: Thread1: signal SIGKILL]

Does anyone know how to get the debugger to work in a UNNotificationServiceExtension?

Comment: Same here. Sometimes my breakpoints work but when I step over lines the debugger detaches.

Comment: Same for me. I set my extension as target and then I start debug but it doesn't stop and sometimes XCode shows SIGKILL but nothing else.

Comment: did you guys had any luck to work that out yet?

Comment: Are you calling any API in your code if so please do it on the global queue?

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem?

Comment: No, I haven't. :(

Comment: Did you find any solution? mine still is waiting to attach!

Answer (score 2):

Don't hit run on Xcode when the debugger is attached to the service extension.

Connect the debugger to the Containing app and run the app. **Then** attach the debugger to the service extension.

I don't know why you can't run it when the debugger is connected to the service extension. I'm *guessing* it has something to do with `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` set to [`com.apple.usernotifications.service`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) and once the OS sees that things go to hell because only the OS should launch the service extension.

Answer (score 1):

2 years ago, I used questioner's way to debug, it works. but recently it doesn't work. and I find another way.

1. connect the device
2. select the xxxNotificationService scheme and run.
3. Xcode will pop up a menu to choose an app to run, select your app.

then, debugger works.

Comment: I did this way and still not working!