# iOS NotificationServiceExtension is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, unnotificationserviceextension

I have enabled NotificationServiceExtension in my app. And done the following

1. Added .apppex under Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded contents
2. Confirmed both deployment target version is 12.0
3. Sending mutable-content": 1 in my apns notification payload
4. Following is my NotificationService's **didReceiveNotificationRequest** method

   ```
   - (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {

   self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

   self.bestAttemptContent.badge = @20;
   self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
   ```

   }

Don't know what I am missing here. Searched and followed so many documents. Nothing seems to be working.

I am using XCode 11.2.1 and  real device with ios version 13.

Comment: Did you check bundle id's as well? Extension's bundle id should be prefixed with the app's bundle id, like:
app: `test.sample.app`,
extension: `test.sample.app.extension`

Comment: yes. Thats looks good.
my app bundle id com.testcompany.appname
Extension bundle id: com.testcompany.appname.<my extension name>

Comment: Do I need to add app group?

Comment: no, app group is not needed.
the only difference I see is according to documentation `"mutable-content"` has to be set to `true` and not `1`

Comment: Tried that too. Not working :(

Comment: How do you know that it's not launching the service extension? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48507016/how-to-debug-an-ios-app-extension/62200031#62200031) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511005/cant-attach-debugger-to-unnotificationserviceextension/62395161#62395161)